# in Java how can I replace "space and dot" to only "dot"?

Tags: java, replace, space

i have for example this:

```
"hello . world . thanks ."
```

and i want to get this:

```
"hello. world. thanks."
```

I have try

```
text = text.replaceAll(" .",".");
text = text.replaceAll(" \\.",".");
text = text.replaceAll(" \\.","\\.");
```

but it doesn´t work. Any solution??

Thanks for all

Comment: What did you get when you try?

Comment: Note that `[.]` (a character class containing only a period) inside a regular expression eliminates the wildcard meaning of the `.` without needing "escapes". Also, the replacement value is *not* treated as a regular expression (but [has other rules](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll(java.lang.String))).

Comment: Your 2nd line works for me: `"hello . world . thanks .".replaceAll(" \\.", ".");`

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`replaceAll` uses regex for the first arguement. If you want something really simple (aka for the example given, assuming your actual problem isn't a lot more complex) you can just use `replace`.

```
text = text.replace(" .", ".");
```

[http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace(java.lang.CharSequence, java.lang.CharSequence)](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29)

Answer (score 5):

Your second method should have worked.

I guess you may have 1 to many space or tabs before `.`.In that case you need to use `+` quantifier to match 1 to many space if you have them

```
text = text.replaceAll("\\s+[.]",".");
```

Since `.` has a special meaning in regex you need to escape it using `\\.` or `[.]` which would treat `.` literally

`\s` is similar to `[ \t\r\n]`

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest you don't use `String.replaceAll` to start with. You don't *need* regular expressions here, so why make it harder for yourself? Use [`String.replace`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#replace%28java.lang.CharSequence,%20java.lang.CharSequence%29) instead.

```
text = text.replace(" .", ".");
```